# Need encoding from images to video on Android

Tags: android, video, encoding, ffmpeg

We need an Android app that can encode a folder of images to a video. I have been looking for solutions a while now, but cannot find anything good. The Android API does not support it. We are trying ffmpeg, but cannot get it to work. We need a working solution, using ffmpeg is not mandatory. A full Android Java solution is also a possibility, since this would work on all Android devices, possibly at the cost of some performance.

The app also needs to be able to add an audio track to the movie if the user chooses to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards,

Aäron

Comment: Hy..Have you found any answer/solution for your problem..if yes then please share it with me..cause i have the same requirement and i am stuck into this and need to get solution urgent..thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

From the FFmpeg FAQ entry "[How do I encode single pictures into movies?](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f)":

> First, rename your pictures to follow a numerical sequence. For example, img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg,... Then you may run:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%d.jpg /tmp/a.mpg
> ```

Adding an audio track should just involve add another input (e.g., `-i audio.mp3`), but could also require explicit [`-map`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options)ing with older versions.